# How to get desktop background after fitted in windows using python?

Tags: python, windows

I'm working on a project and need to get the desktop background. However, I've encountered an issue with how Windows applies different fit modes to the background. The available options are Fill, Fit, Stretch, Tile, Centre, and Span.

Currently, I've managed to retrieve the background image path and the fit mode, but I'm struggling with understanding how Windows applies these fit modes to the background

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.